# How Angular dynamic forms are bound to variables;

Tags: angular

(Google Chinese to English)
Excuse me,
How Angular's dynamic form is bound to a defined data model object to achieve real-time response of form data to the model object is similar to Angular's two-way binding effect.

(Google Chinese to English)
I defined a data model object, defined a dynamic form object, and then bound the data model object to the dynamic model.
However, the form values of the dynamic form are not mapped to the bound data model object.

```
/*Model Object*/
export Class StudentModel{
    Name:string
}

@Component(....)
 export Class  OneComponent implements OnInit{

 public validateForm :FormGroup;

 public studentModel:StudentModel={ Name:'XiaoMing' }

  constructor(
    private _fb: FormBuilder
  ) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    /**表单初始赋值 */
    this.validateForm = this._fb.group({
      Name: [this.studentModel.Name]
  })
 }
}
```

When the HTML is bound to the form, the form data can be changed directly to the this.studentModel.Name property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like @vadi has the answer you are looking for.

But in case that isn't what you are asking ...

If you are instead asking how to match up the form values with the model values after completing the form, you can do this:

```
const updatedStudent = { ...this.studentModel, ...this.validateForm.value };
```

This will take the data from the original model, including any properties that may not appear on the form (say your model had an id property for example.)

Then overwrite the model data with any user-entries from the values on the form.

The result is an object with the updated values. You can than use that object to put/post to your data store.

**UPDATE**

The answer to your question is "no", reactive forms does *not* have two-way binding.

The primary point of reactive forms is immutability. So it *intentionally* does *not* update your model.

If you want to watch for *any* changes to the form, you can use this:

```
this.validateForm.valueChanges.subscribe(val => {
  // here goes all update related code
});
```

But if you *really* need to have the model change as the user makes changes and you want two-way binding, consider using template-driven forms instead.

Comment: Thank you for your help.But does Angular dynamic form have such a mechanism, similar to ngModel two-way binding, when the UI interface fills in or modifies the value, you can directly assign the value to the bound model object, in this case it can be directly modified automatically. this.studentModel.Name this object value, instead of manually extracting the value in the form once, assign it to this.studentModel.Name.
Although this is also possible, I just want to make the code more concise and elegant.

Answer (score 0):

If I right understand, the question is how to update `this.studentModel.Name` every time the form changes value in template, and update `validateForm.controls['Name']`, if `this.studentModel.Name` has changed. You need to do it manually in Angular reactive form. Here you've just set an initial value for `Name`:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
  this.validateForm = this._fb.group({
    Name: [this.studentModel.Name]
  })
}
```

Through the [valueChanges](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms#displaying-a-form-control-value) observable you can listen for changes in the form's value in the template. So to get updated value from `validateForm` `Name` you can subscribe to valuveChanges and update `this.studentModel` `Name` property:

```
this.validateForm.get('Name').valueChanges.subscribe(val => {
  // here goes all update related code
   this.studentModel.Name = val;
});
```

To update `validateForm` control value, you can use `patchValue`:

```
this.validateForm.get('Name').patchValue(this.studentModel.Name);
```

Comment: Thank you for your help.But does Angular dynamic form have such a mechanism, similar to ngModel two-way binding, when the UI interface fills in or modifies the value, you can directly assign the value to the bound model object, in this case it can be directly modified automatically. this.studentModel.Name this object value, instead of manually extracting the value in the form once, assign it to this.studentModel.Name.
Although this is also possible, I just want to make the code more concise and elegant.

Comment: @崔云博 No, Angular reactive forms do not allow to make it that way. So if there is a need to update, for example, `this.studentModel.Name`, you need to subscribe to form value changes.

Answer (score 0):

(currently 15:21 Chinese time, Google Translate)
Thank you very much for your reply.
In fact, my data model defines more than a dozen models. The examples in the problem are just demonstrations. I don't want to bind the corresponding values ​​one by one in this way, and I don't want to be like this:

```
Class StudentModel{
      Name:string,
      Age:string,
      Birth:moment
      ..... (many attributes)
    }

    Class OneComponent implements OnInit{
      Public validateForm :FormGroup;

      Public studentModel:StudentModel={ Name:'XiaoMing' }

      Constructor(
         Private _fb: FormBuilder
       ) {}

       ngOnInit(): void {
        /**Form initial assignment */
       this.validateForm = this._fb.group({
          Name: [this.studentModel.name],
          Age: [this.studentModel.age],
          Birth: [this.studentModel.birth],
          .......(many form definitions)
       })
      }

 ///When saving the form, assign the values ​​in the form to the data model.
 ///Because the remote interface method parameters are called, the requirement is the 
 ///Strong Type parameter of the Student
     Public ToSave():void{
       //This talks about using a loash.js library.
       // Assign the object value on this.validateForm.getRawValue to
       //this.studentModel object
       assignIn(
          this.studentModel,
          this.validateForm.getRawValue
       )
     }
    }
```

In fact, I hope that ngModel can be bound in both directions like a template form. When the value of the UI input changes, the data model object corresponding to the form binding changes at the same time.
But it seems that dynamic forms don't seem to support this mechanism, you need to manually take values ​​and assign them to the specified model object.
Thank you for your help~~~~@DeborahK and @Vadi

Comment: To follow standard processes here, please update your question with this information instead of enhancing your question in an "answer". That keeps all of the important details about the question in one place. Thanks!